# Syncronize Linux /etc/ directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync, sync

I have virtual machine with Linux (Ubuntu server) which is used as prototype for other machines. Sometimes I make changes in prototype system and want to import this changes at some other machine.

I know about Puppet, cfengine and FAI but want something easy for example rsync script which will work through ssh when it needed.

Main goal is /etc/ directory. But I don't want to syncronize some private files for example /etc/passwd /etc/shadow and so on. I don't know all of it.

Are there tips for my task ? May be someone have such rsync script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution might be to setup git.

- Setup a git repository in your `/etc` directory.
- Setup an ignore file to exclude things you don't want to migrate to the remote system.
- Add everything not ignored into your repository.
- On the production pull from the dev repository as needed.

Comment: Really good approach with versioning. Remains only determine ignorance files.

Comment: Only you can determine that.  I might start with a simple `grep pat * -R` for the hostname, and any other facts that are local to the system.  You could also setup a third testing machine to try on the process initially.

Comment: looks like etckeeper could realy help you here. http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/

Answer (score 3):

You already have the answer. rsync can do what you want, it runs over ssh when you want it to, and it can easily ignore files you don't want it to sync:

```
rsync -avP source:/etc/ /etc/ --exclude-from list-of-files-to-exclude
```

And just add a list of files to exclude to the `list-of-files-to-exclude` flie. For example:

```
$ cat list-of-files-to-exclude
/passwd
/shadow
```

Of course I would still strongly recommend version control, and something more sophisticated like puppet. And make sure you take care of file ownership and permissions.